# transition delay on :before content

Tags: css, css-transitions

I'm trying to set a `transition-delay` on a :before-element, but it doesn't really want to do what I want it to.

The transition is the change of an image, as I want it to change a second after the user has hovered the div in which the image is.

I have set up a [JSFiddle-demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hf6rpg9p/) to help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the following code. It's better to use transition on a background image.

```
div {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

i {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background:greenyellow;
    display:block;
    margin:150px auto;
    -webkit-transition: background 1s;
}

i:before {
    content: "";
    background: url('http://hph-e.dk/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/house.png')no-repeat;
    -webkit-transition: background 1s;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}

div:hover i:before {
    content: "";
    background: url('http://www.clker.com/cliparts/U/6/e/C/Z/l/green-house-icon-md.png') no-repeat;
    -webkit-transition: background 1s;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

An example: http://jsfiddle.net/hf6rpg9p/4/